# How to add a quantity field to Stripe Charge? JavaScript

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, stripe.js

While creating a Stripe Checkouts form, I can't seem to find any option for adding a quantity to the Stripe Charge method so that the client can see how many the customer ordered.  I've searched [Stripe's API](https://stripe.com/docs/api) docs and can't find anything on adding quantity to a charge method (The subscription plan has a quantity parameter, but that's not what I'm looking for).  Is there a keyword I'm missing?  Or is quantity just not supported by Stripe?

```
stripe(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY).charges.create({
    quantity: 2,
    receipt_email: body.stripeEmail,
    amount: body.amount,
    currency: body.currency,
    source: body.stripeToken, 
    description: body.description
  }, (err, charge) => {
    console.log(body.amount, body.currency);
    const status = err ? 400: 200;
    const message = err ? err.message: 'Payment successfully completed!';
    res.writeHead(status, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    return res.end('<h1>' + message + '</h1>');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Quantity is not a property available on the Charge object, for one-off charges like this. If you wish to offer users the ability to purchase in quantity you should define this in your own application logic, calculate a total, and then instruct Stripe to charge the final amount. You could store quantity on [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#metadata) for your own records. Or, perhaps, you could look into using [Orders](https://stripe.com/docs/orders).

```
stripe.charges.create({
    metadata: {'quantity': 2, 'order_id': 'A6735'},
    receipt_email: body.stripeEmail,
    amount: body.amount,
    currency: body.currency,
    source: body.stripeToken, 
    description: body.description
})
```

...